# name 'get_config' is not defined

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython

when i am working with ipython notebook, i want to run a notebook server. I followed the official [tutorial](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html)  However, when I want to obtain the `get_config()` function as said in the tutorial, I come across with the name `get_config` is not defined problem.
I searched the internet and found the [page](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/get-config-td5058343.html) . However, there is no `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`  file in my ubuntu 12.04 system. What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you edit the full stacktrace of the error into your question?

Comment: IPython is old name. Now it is known as Jupyter. You visit https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and follow the tutorial if your problem has not been solved yet. After installing Jupyter you can generate config file using `jupyter` command and edit the config file with the code that you have specified. Let me know if you face any problem, I will help you with a PDF.

Comment: Better is to install Anaconda (It has Jupyter pre-installed) from https://www.anaconda.com/download/ and try that I suggested above.

Answer (score 16):

Paul Ivanov stated in the forum post:

> get_config is available only inside the configuration files at 
>   load time.

So you can only use `get_config` in configuration files, not in an `ipython` session.

You basically have two options:

If you only want to make temporary changes, you can use the `%config` magic. But note that changes are lost after you exit the session.

The documentation says:

> At present, this only affects the current session - changes you make to config are not saved anywhere. Also, some options are only read when IPython starts, so they can’t be changed like this.

The second option is to create a new profile. (see `ipython profile help`). Each profile comes with its own config files. You can find the files by executing:

```
ls $(ipython locate profile <your-profile-name>)
```

You can add your configuration options to a specific `*_config.py` file.

For a further reading, see ipython's [config intro](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html).

Comment: thanks! I followed the document you present and get my job done!

Comment: @zishuiym, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you to solve this issue. This is StackExchanges way of marking questions as solved (not to mention all that bonus reputation :))