# How to rectify this error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
    python serve.py
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  .format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serve.py", line 1, in <module>
    from CTFd import create_app
  File "/home/rajat/Downloads/CTFd/CTFd/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils import get_config, set_config
     ImportError: cannot import name 'get_config'
```

Don't know what is causing this error

Tried pip install utils

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666134/name-get-config-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

`from utils import get_config, set_config`

looks like `get_config` does not exists in `utils` library.

I think you need to give more details about your problem.